# I an't connect robomongo to vagrant mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, puphpet

I have vagrant box create with https://puphpet.com/ with mongodb 2.6 on nginx and ubuntu 14.04.
Also I have on my host os ubunut with mongodb. I can connect on the host mongodb. But not on vagrant. How I can connect to the vagrant mongodb with robomongo.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is if you defined a fixed IP (look in `config.yaml` for `private_network`), you can connect with

```
mongo <vm_private_ip>:<port>/<db if you have one or blank>
```

If you only have the hostname defined in Vagrantfile, you will need to add your host into `/etc/hosts` file and forward the mongo port (look `forwarded_port` in the config file) so you can connect

```
mongo <vm_hostname>:<port>/<db if you have one or blank>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh tunnel with private key 'puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa'.
And in connection tab set up the address of MongoDB server 127.0.0.1